# Bluetooth keyboard and mouse not responding properly Pi4

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, mouse

I got Pi4 for about a year now. I have a keyboard+mouse combo with one bluetooth dongle. It had been working perfectly fine but now there are problems. If I take the keyboard and mouse closer to the Pi, it works but from a mere 1.5 meters or so it does not. I tried another mouse with a different dongle and the same problem persists. I checked the older ones (keyboard+mouse combo) on a different laptop and they work perfectly fine from a longer distance.
It is definitely not the range, batteries or the keyboard+mouse problem. It has do with Pi itself.
Any ideas how to fix this please?
Thank you

Comment: `It had been working perfectly fine but now there are problems` ... what changed about the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hello Jsotola.. Thank you for replying. Nothing changed. I am not a programmer. I just use it to watch movies on the TV. I download movies on a separate PC and then connect an external USB drive to the Pi to watch.